# Media player not working in Android version >=4.0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing a simple radio streaming application to play radio using  a URL. This application is working in all the versions except for V>=4.0

Do anyone have any Idea over this.

```
   initializeUIElements();
    StartPlaying();

     private void initializeUIElements() {

    buttonPlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    playSeekBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
}


 private void startPlaying() {


    initializeMediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            Log.i("on prepared", "on prepared");
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    player.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener(){
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"An error happened while preparing radio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           player.reset();
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        return false;
        } 

});

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
   player.reset();
    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource("http://***************");
        player.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

            Log.i("percent", ""+percent);
           if( (percent!=0)||(percent==100) )
           {

               playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               buttonPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }


        }
    });
```

In Android version 4.0, It is giving an error as:

```
  11-23 13:06:37.329: E/MediaPlayer(4011): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

and Player.bufferingUpdateListener() is not called. Here It is showing just that playseekbar revolving and revolving.. Please help on this.

Comment: may be a problem with your streaming datasource.

Comment: No.. because It is working on other devices Version<4.0

Comment: if you want to give me your link, i can try it for you my devices. because it can be device specific error.

Comment: Use this link: http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138"

Comment: It is not working me too, on 4.0.3.  But it is shoutcast, maybe you can try to use vitamio plugin. http://vitamio.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a problem with your particular device. Try running the same on 4.0 emulator.

Comment: Yes. It is working on emulator, but It is not working on the device. Why is this case??